# Fourier transformation of $Ae^{-x^2+ax}$

Tags: calculus, mathematical-physics, fourier-transform

I'm fairly new to Fourier transformation. I know how to find the gaussian intergral of e^(-x^2). However this question has an addition ax term in the power of the exponential  f(x)=Ae^(-x^-2+ax).

This was the given the solution. Please click on 
[Fourier transformation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oKeBQ.png) to see image

But I still don't understand what happened from line 2 to line 3 and reading the explanation doesn't really help either. An explicit computation would be most appreciated!

Comment: They have "completed the square" in the exponent.

Comment: Are you still interested in seeing a step-by-step solution? This is really just what Keith McClary said.